# IF Based FOR Loop Not Inserting Multiple Rows - PHP

Tags: php, sql, for-loop, if-statement, prepared-statement

I have not been able to get this to work. I either get one entry inserted, or none. I'm trying to add rows based on whether the user had the checkbox in the previous form checked. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

If you are able, can you show an example of what I'm doing wrong and what the correct way is? I appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

```
$todo_toaddornot=$_POST['toaddornot'];
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO todo_list
(todo_key,todo_name,todo_desc,todo_parent,todo_keydate,todo_assigned,todo_daysfrom,todo_daysrelation)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam('sssssssss',$todo_key,$todo_name,$todo_desc,$todo_parent,$todo_keydate,$todo_assigned,$todo_daysfrom,$todo_daysrelation,$todo_status);
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['name']);$i++)
{   //If Mark Yes Then Insert Task
    if($todo_toaddornot[$i]==='Yes')
    { 
        $todo_key=$_POST['listing_key'][$i];
        $todo_name=$_POST['name'][$i];
        $todo_desc=$_POST['desc'][$i];
        $todo_parent=$_POST['parenttodo'][$i];
        $todo_keydate=$_POST['keydate'][$i];
        $todo_assigned=$_POST['assignment'][$i];
        $todo_daysfrom=$_POST['daysfrom'][$i];
        $todo_daysrelation=$_POST['daysrelation'][$i];
//1 = status of Not Complete
        $todo_status='1';
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

**UPDATED 07.23.2019**
I was able to get it to insert, but only the first instance. (I simplified it to narrow down the problem.)

```
$todo_toaddornot=$_POST['toaddornot'];
$todo_name = $_POST['taskname'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO todo_list(todo_name) todo_name)");  
$stmt->bindParam(':todo_name',$todo_name);
for($i=0;$i<count($todo_name);$i++)
{  
if($todo_toaddornot[$i]==='Yes'){ 
$todo_name=$_POST['taskname'][$i];
$stmt->execute();
}}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the `todo_status` into the fields list in the query

Comment: @AlonEitan Ok. Added. But still won't work. 

Comment: Yeah, well, another issue is you're using both `PDO` and `mysqli` at the same time - Choose one mysql extension and stick with it

Comment: @AlonEitan I was able to get it to the point of inserting the first instance. Updated code above.